# auto generate random number inside div box?

Tags: javascript, html

how to auto-generate random number inside the div box? and change again after refreshing the page.

**HTML code.**

```
    <div class="grid" data-row="0" data-column="0"></div>
    <div class="grid" data-row="0" data-column="1"></div>
    <div class="grid" data-row="0" data-column="2"></div>
    <div class="grid" data-row="0" data-column="3"></div>
    <div class="grid" data-row="0" data-column="4"></div>

    ......

    <div class="grid" data-row="4" data-column="0"></div>
    <div class="grid" data-row="4" data-column="1"></div>
    <div class="grid" data-row="4" data-column="2"></div>
    <div class="grid" data-row="4" data-column="3"></div>
    <div class="grid" data-row="4" data-column="4"></div>
```

**JS code**.

```
function random() {
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 1);
  $(".grid").text(x);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "change again after refresh the page."? What is your requirement? Everything you do in JavaScript in the DOM will be lost after  a page refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use JQuery's `.each()` method to loop through all the `div` element and generate random number inside that loop. Keep generating the random number and keep applying to `div`. See below

```js
$('.grid').each(function () {
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 1);
  $(this).text(x)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid" data-row="0" data-column="0"></div>
<div class="grid" data-row="0" data-column="1"></div>
<div class="grid" data-row="0" data-column="2"></div>
<div class="grid" data-row="0" data-column="3"></div>
<div class="grid" data-row="0" data-column="4"></div>
<div class="grid" data-row="4" data-column="0"></div>
<div class="grid" data-row="4" data-column="1"></div>
<div class="grid" data-row="4" data-column="2"></div>
<div class="grid" data-row="4" data-column="3"></div>
<div class="grid" data-row="4" data-column="4"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this should help you,, I commented the code a little, might be of help

```js
// get all grid rows
var arr = document.querySelectorAll('.grid');
// loop over grid array
arr.forEach( function(el){
  // generate random number
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 1);
  // pass that number to element node
  el.innerText = x ;
});
```

```html
<div class="grid" data-row="4" data-column="0"></div>
<div class="grid" data-row="4" data-column="1"></div>
<div class="grid" data-row="4" data-column="2"></div>
<div class="grid" data-row="4" data-column="3"></div>
<div class="grid" data-row="4" data-column="4"></div>
```