# Add Random div class value every 60 seconds in multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a page that looks like

```
    <a href="#" onclick="go('register')">
      <img class="img" src="img/192.webp" alt="box set" />
      <div class="name" style="line-height: 2">box set</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item ">
    <a href="#" onclick="go('register')">
      <img class="img" src="img/182.webp" alt="battery" />
      <div class="name" style="line-height: 2">battery</div>
```

I was wondering if there is a way that I could insert a div class randomly "percent**x**" (random between 1-100), so when the page is loaded, it would look like:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="go('register')">
      <img class="img" src="img/192.webp" alt="box set" />
      <div class="name" style="line-height: 2">box set</div>
      <div class="percent75"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item ">
    <a href="#" onclick="go('register')">
      <img class="img" src="img/182.webp" alt="battery" />
      <div class="name" style="line-height: 2">battery</div>
      <div class="percent61"></div>
```

Then change every 60 second

```
    <a href="#" onclick="go('register')">
      <img class="img" src="img/192.webp" alt="box set" />
      <div class="name" style="line-height: 2">box set</div>
      <div class="percent21"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item ">
    <a href="#" onclick="go('register')">
      <img class="img" src="img/182.webp" alt="battery" />
      <div class="name" style="line-height: 2">battery</div>
      <div class="percent95"></div>
```

Regarding this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809795/auto-generate-random-number-inside-div-box)

```js
$('.percent').each(function () {
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  $(this).text(x)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="percent"></div>
```

How can I modify this code for my needs?

### Update

@ebod here is the modified code,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="percent"></div>
<div id="pp" class="group_flex">
<a class="items " href="#" onclick="go('daftar')"><img loading="lazy" class="gimg" src="img/18.webp" alt="Jagung" />  <div class="gname">Jagung</div><div class="percent52"></div></a>
<a class="items " href="#" onclick="go('daftar')"><img loading="lazy" class="gimg" src="img/77.webp" alt="Semangka" />  <div class="gname">Semangka</div><div class="percent44"></div></a>
<a class="items " href="#" onclick="go('daftar')"><img loading="lazy" class="gimg" src="img/109.webp" alt="Nanas" />  <div class="gname">Nanas</div><div class="percent59"></div></a>
</div>
```

and

```
function additems(){
    document.getElementById('pp').className = 'items ';
}
function addhot(){
document.getElementById('pp').setAttribute( "class", "items hot" );
// need some code to add <img class="overlay-img" src="css/img/logo-hot.gif" >
}
  
setInterval(function() {
    $('div[class*="percent"]').each(function () {
            var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            if (x < 50 ){
            $(this).attr('class', 'percent' + x);
            additems()
            } else {
            addhot()
         }    
    });
}, 2000);
```

using the var x value

if (x < 50) `<a class="items "` did not change any

if (x > 50 )  `<a class="items "` change to `<a class="items hot "` next add another class `<img class="overlay-img" src="css/img/logo-hot.gif" >` for cosmetic purposes.

however, this code only change the first children of group_flex class, and for some reason the value < 50 sometimes change the class items to items hot.

Comment: Wrap your function in a [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) function: `setInterval(() => $('.percent').each(...), 60 * 1000)`

Comment: I have added the supplementary material in an answer in the form of a question update. However that may not have been necessary, since you have asked a new question. Could you confirm that they are the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the snippet you provided, you can use `$('div[class*="percent"]')` which will select class names containing the substring 'percent'. I would suggest using ID names if you want the random percentages to be unique per div.

Otherwise, the solution below will overwrite all class names every 60 seconds that contain 'percent' with 'percentx' where x is the randomly generated number.

```
<div class="percent"></div>
<div class="percent"></div>
<div class="percent"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
setInterval(function() {
    $('div[class*="percent"]').each(function () {
            var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            $(this).attr('class', 'percent' + x);
    });
}, 60000);
</script>
```

Comment: @Atms No problem! Just an FYI that posts are limited to only one question. I believe the original question has been answered, so if possible, please move the new question to a separate post and I'd be happy to help!

Comment: ok i will make new thread for this, thank you in advance

Comment: if you don't mind please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76839796/change-multiple-class-on-conditions-every-x-seconds