# Change multiple classes on conditions every x seconds

Tags: javascript, html

This script does change all the `<div class="percentx">` randomly let's say from `<div class="percent31">` to `<div class="percent52">` (value between 1-100). It runs well.

I try to make some functions that if the `x` value `> 50` it will change all the children classes under `<div id="pp" class="group_flex">` that match `percentx` `> 50` change `<a class="items"` to `<a class="items hot"` also add new class `<img class="overlay-img" src="css/img/logo-hot.gif" >`

Next, if the x value <50 it changes back to `<a class="items"`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="percent"></div>
<div id="pp" class="group_flex">
    <a class="items " href="#" onclick="go('daftar')"><img loading="lazy" class="gimg" src="img/18.webp" alt="Jagung" />  <div class="gname">Jagung</div><div class="percent52"></div></a>
    <a class="items " href="#" onclick="go('daftar')"><img loading="lazy" class="gimg" src="img/77.webp" alt="Semangka" />  <div class="gname">Semangka</div><div class="percent44"></div></a>
    <a class="items " href="#" onclick="go('daftar')"><img loading="lazy" class="gimg" src="img/109.webp" alt="Nanas" />  <div class="gname">Nanas</div><div class="percent59"></div></a>
</div>
```

```
function additems(){
    document.getElementById('pp').className = 'items ';
}
function addhot(){
    document.getElementById('pp').setAttribute( "class", "items hot" );
    // need some code to add <img class="overlay-img" src="css/img/logo-hot.gif" >
}
  
setInterval(function() {
    $('div[class*="percent"]').each(function () {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        if (x < 50 ){
            $(this).attr('class', 'percent' + x);
            additems()
        } else {
        addhot()
        }    
    });
}, 2000);
```

However, the function only changes the first children of `<div id="pp" class="group_flex">` and I can not find any reference to add a new class:

`<img class="overlay-img" src="css/img/logo-hot.gif">`

Any help would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use a class with a variable suffix, it'll become too cumbersome. [Data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) are made for elements that need to have minor data assigned to it such as numbers (any value of a HTML attribute is always a string so numbers must be converted to a real number once it is extracted) or strings. See JavaScript source references¹.
- An element that acts as an overlay usually requires the CSS properties [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index):

  - The parent element is assigned `position: relative`.
  - The overlay element is assigned `position: absolute` and `z-index: 1` or greater. It is placed within the parent element.

  See CSS source references¹ and references³.
- In order to access more than one element, you need to collect all of them into a NodeList with [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- `.className` property is limited in that it overwrites existing classes unless the string value of class is concatenated (which is more trouble than it's worth). Use [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property instead -- it doesn't overwrite values -- it accesses and manipulates a class value with it's own methods: `.add()`, `.remove()`, `.replace()`, `.toggle()`, and `.contains()`.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Define "int" outside of function.
let int = null;
// Define "idx" outside of function.
let idx = 0;

/**
 * Assign a given item's [data-rating] a given number and assign it 
 * class ".hot" if [data-rating] is greater than 50 or remove class ".hot" 
 * if 50 or lower.
 * @param {Object<DOM>} item - An element.
 * @param {number} rating - A number assigned to [data-rating].
 */
function setHot(item, rating) { 
  item.dataset.rating = rating; // ¹
  // For demo purposes.
  console.log("Item rating ([data-rating]): " + rating);
  if (rating > 50) {
    item.classList.add("hot");
  } else {
    item.classList.remove("hot");
  }
}

// Redefine "int" as an interval driven function.
int = setInterval(() => {
  // Collect all ".item" into a NodeList.
  const items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
  /* 
  Define "item" as a specific ".item" within NodeList "items" by it's 
  index position ("idx"). 
  */
  let item = items[idx];
  // For demo purposes.
  console.log("Item index (idx): " + idx);
  /* ¹ 
  Randomly assign a number to "rating" in the range of 1 to 100. 
  */
  let rating = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  /* 
  Call function setHot() passing "item" and "rating". 
  */
  setHot(item, rating);
  // Increment "idx" by 1.
  idx++;
  // If "idx" is greater than the last index of "items"...
  if (idx > items.length - 1) {
    // ...assign 0 to "idx".
    idx = 0;
  }
  // Call this function every 2 seconds.
}, 2000);
```

```css
:root {
  font: 2ch/1.15 "Segoe UI";
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 60vw;
}

.item {
  /* ¹ 
  Any element within it's borders that has "position: absolute" 
  can be positioned by referencing ".item"'s borders. 
  */
  position: relative;
  width: 18vw;
  height: 18vw;
}

.icon {
  /* ³ 
  By referencing ".item"'s borders with properties "top", "bottom", 
  "left", and/or "right", ".icon" can be positioned. 
  */
  position: absolute;
  /* ³ 
  This allows ".icon" to sit above ".image" like an overlay. 
  */
  z-index: 1;
  /* ³ 
  This sets ".icon" at the top of ".item". 
  */
  top: 0;
  /* ³ 
  This sets ".icon" at the right of ".item". 
  */
  right: 0;
  /* ⁴ 
  This hides ".icon". 
  */
  display: none;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  max-width: 2rem;
}

.image {
  /* ⁵ 
  See reference³. 
  */
  position: absolute;
  /* ⁵ 
  See reference³. 
  */
  top: 0;
  /* ⁵ 
  See reference³. 
  */
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.title {
  /* ⁶ 
  See reference³. 
  */
  position: absolute;
  /* ⁶ 
  See reference³. 
  */
  z-index: 1;
  /* ⁶ 
  See reference³. 
  */
  bottom: 0;
  /* ⁶ 
  See reference³. 
  */
  left: 0;
  /* ⁶ 
  See reference³. 
  */
  right: 0;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: cyan;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

/* ² 
When ".hot" is assigned to ".item", it will have a red outline. 
*/
.hot {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}

/* ² 
When ".hot" is assigned to ".item", ".title" text will be gold. 
*/
.hot .title {
  color: gold;
}

/* ² 
When ".hot" is assigned to ".item", ".icon" appears. 
*/
.hot .icon {
  display: block;
}

/*
For demo purposes.
*/ 
.as-console-row { visibility: collapse; }
.as-console-row:nth-last-of-type(-n+2) { visibility: visible; }
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <!-- 
      - Item's borders are referenced by it's icon, image, and title 
        for their position within it.
        See CSS source references¹.
      - When it is assigned class ".hot"... 
        ...it will be outlined in red...
        ...it's icon will appear...
        ...it's title will be gold.
        See CSS source references².
      - .item
        Each item needs only one common class. 
      - [data-rating]
        Use data-* attribute to assign numerical values. 
        See JavaScript source references¹.
      -->
      <figure class="item" data-rating="20">
        <!--
        - .icon
          Each item has an icon that sits on top of the item's image. 
          See CSS source references³.
          By default, it is hidden.  
          See CSS source references⁴.
        -->
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6XQDBxF/hot.png" class="icon">
        <!--
        - .image
          Each item has an image that sits below the icon and title. 
          See CSS source references⁵.
        -->
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/7N8gHf9/red.jpg" class="image">
        <!--
        .title
          Each item has a caption that sits on top of the item's image. 
          See CSS source references⁶.
        -->
        <figcaption class="title">Red</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <figure class="item hot" data-rating="88">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6XQDBxF/hot.png" class="icon">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/BZg3Jpz/white.jpg" class="image">
        <figcaption class="title">White</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <figure class="item" data-rating="50">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6XQDBxF/hot.png" class="icon">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/jG4NGb1/blue.png" class="image">
        <figcaption class="title">Blue</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```